# What tests do I need to run to conclude that I cannot use ARIMA for a series?

Tags: arima, white-noise

I am trying to fit an ARMA model to a stationary series.

Following the methodology from a paper I regress my data on a constant and look at the Q-stat for lagged value to check if there is serial correlation in the data. The Q-stat p-value > 0.05 and 0.1 at all the lags which in my understanding means that the data is uncorrelated but does that mean that it is white noise? Are there an y other tests that I can use to see if the data really is white noise?

Thanks!

Comment: There are two conditions which may deem your series inappropriate for an ARMA model: (a) Your series is not and cannot be transformed to a stationary process (not your case apparently), and (b) your series is white noise (most likely your case). I'm quite confident that no statistical test will ever turn white noise into something forecastable. What you should really be looking for is a set of features that you should introduce to your model as regressors and use a conventional (non-time series) method to predict your response.

Comment: For it to be white noise it should have constant mean, constant variance and 0 autocorrelation at all lags $k>0$. The q-stat indicate it to be white noise, but I have seen in a book "Applied Time Series Analysis" by woodward, gray and elliott that they look at the residuals of a misspecified model to see if the autcorrelation is really 0 and they conclude that it is time-varying and that ARMA can be used. Is there a test to look at that? Does this has something to do with heteroskedasticity in residuals?

Comment: Heteroskedasticity and autocorrelation are two different things and are treated with different techniques but if your series is white noise you can't really deal with either of them. If for any reason the results of the [Ljung-Box test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ljung%E2%80%93Box_test) are not sufficient for you then you can always try fitting a simple linear model to your data and use the standard OLS diagnostics (e.g. residuals plot) to check for residuals autocorrelation. I can only guess that this is what your book means, but it won't be more powerful than the Q-statistic.